# Algorithm incorrectly says ray intersects triangle above it

Tags: c, algorithm

This is one of many similar ray-triangle intersection algorithms. Every other algorithm I've tested also returns true for these numbers, while the ray clearly does not cross the triangle. The ray goes from y=0 to y=1, while the triangle is flat across y = 2.3.

This is not a winding issue, as it should never return true (winding issues would explain false negatives, not false positives).

All code necessary to reproduce in C or C++ is included here.

What am I missing?

```
#define vector(a,b,c) \
(a)[0] = (b)[0] - (c)[0];   \
(a)[1] = (b)[1] - (c)[1];   \
(a)[2] = (b)[2] - (c)[2];

#define crossProduct(a,b,c) \
(a)[0] = (b)[1] * (c)[2] - (c)[1] * (b)[2]; \
(a)[1] = (b)[2] * (c)[0] - (c)[2] * (b)[0]; \
(a)[2] = (b)[0] * (c)[1] - (c)[0] * (b)[1];

#define innerProduct(v,q) \
((v)[0] * (q)[0] + \
(v)[1] * (q)[1] + \
(v)[2] * (q)[2])

#define DOT(A,B) \
((A)[0] * (B)[0] + (A)[1] * (B)[1] + (A)[2] * (B)[2])


    int intersect3D_RayTriangle( )
{
    //    dir, w0, w;           // ray vectors
    double     r, a, b;              // params to calc ray-plane intersect

    // output: Point* I

    //Ray R
    double origin[3] = {0,0,0};//{orig[0],orig[1],orig[2]};
    double direction[3] = {0,1,0};//{dir[0],dir[1],dir[2]};

    //Triangle T
    double corner1[3] = {3,    2.3,    -4 };//{v0[0],v0[1],v0[2]};
    double corner2[3] = {-7,   2.3,    2};//{v1[0],v1[1],v1[2]};
    double corner3[3] = {3,    2.3,    2};// v2[0],v2[1],v2[2]};

    //     Vector    u, v, n;              // triangle vectors
    double u[3] = {corner2[0]-corner1[0],corner2[1]-corner1[1],corner2[2]-corner1[2]};
    double v[3] = {corner3[0]-corner1[0],corner3[1]-corner1[1],corner3[2]-corner1[2]};
    double n[3] = {0,0,0};
    double e1[3],e2[3],h[3],q[3];
    double f;



    // get triangle edge vectors and plane normal
    crossProduct(n, u, v);
    if ((n[0] == 0) && (n[1] == 0) && (n[2] == 0))             // triangle is wonky
        return -1;                  // do not deal with this case

    // dir = R.P1 - R.P0;              // ray direction vector
    double rayDirection[3] = {direction[0] - origin[0], direction[1] - origin[1], direction[2] - origin[2]};

    //w0 = R.P0 - T.V0;
    double w0[3]  = {origin[0] - corner1[0], origin[1] - corner1[1], origin[2] - corner1[2]};

    a = -DOT(n,w0);
    b = DOT(n,rayDirection);
    if (fabs(b) < __DBL_EPSILON__) {     // ray is  parallel to triangle plane
        if (a == 0)                 // ray lies in triangle plane
            return 2;
        else return 0;              // ray disjoint from plane
    }

    // get intersect point of ray with triangle plane
    r = a / b;
    if (r < 0.0)                    // ray goes away from triangle
        return 0;                   // => no intersect
    // for a segment, also test if (r > 1.0) => no intersect

    //*I = R.P0 + r * dir;            // intersect point of ray and plane
    double I[3] = {0,0,0};
    I[0] = origin[0] + rayDirection[0] * r;
    I[1] = origin[1] + rayDirection[1] * r;
    I[2] = origin[2] + rayDirection[2] * r;

    // is I inside T?
    double    uu, uv, vv, wu, wv, D;
    uu = DOT(u,u);
    uv = DOT(u,v);
    vv = DOT(v,v);

    double w[3] = {0,0,0};
    w[0] = I[0] - corner1[0];
    w[1] = I[1] - corner1[1];
    w[2] = I[2] - corner1[2];


    wu = DOT(w,u);
    wv = DOT(w,v);
    D = uv * uv - uu * vv;

    // get and test parametric coords
    double s, t;
    s =  (uv * wv - vv * wu) / D;
    if (s < 0.0 || s > 1.0)         // I is outside T
        return 0;
    t = (uv * wu - uu * wv) / D;
    if (t < 0.0 || (s + t) > 1.0)  // I is outside T
        return 0;

    return 1;                       // I is in T
}
```

Comment: Hello Chilton, welcome to SO ! Please be sure to read the following link on how to ask "good" questions. It will help people to better answer you with relevant answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Noted, edited. Thank you.

Comment: Curious. Why mostly use `double`, yet `float` with dot products?

Comment: Good catch, the original of this algorithm used floats for everything, and I need doubles. I thought I had changed all of them, but missed those. Unfortunately, I tried changing it to doubles and it still returns true.

Comment: @ChiltonWebb Please clarify do you expect `int intersect3D_RayTriangle( )` to return1 and it does not?  It returns 1 for me.

Comment: Also unclear " ray clearly does not cross the triangle" and "The ray goes from y=0 to y=1" - this sounds like a segment.  I'd expect a [ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)#Ray) to start at `y=0` and go indefinitely in the direction of `y=1`.  IOWs, it does intersect.

Comment: Debugging output statements are your friend. You could easily add output statements that let you trace what happens in your code.

Comment: In terms of the the actual problem you have, think about this: your ray, if it was longer, would definitely go through the triangle. So, it seems likely that this is what confuses the code. Ask: how does your code treat intersection points located along the vector but not in the ray? In particular, what is the value of "r" in this case?

Comment: Why not test if `if (r > 1.0) return 0;` if ray is really a segment?

Comment: @chux, I expect it to return 0. The ray does not intersect the triangle at any point.

Comment: chux and jwimberley, you are both correct. I now realize the problem all along has been on the other side of the screen. I went looking for line segment intersection, ended up with ray intersection, and completely forgot that none of these algorithms are using the magnitude of the ray to determine the end point. They're just casting the ray off into space.

Comment: okay, so, as I suspected earlier I was missing something super obvious. Of course all of these algorithms would work right, they're doing a ray cast and not a line segment. What is the protocol now for pointing out that this has been solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code works fine for "rays".

OP expected that that "ray" code functioned like a "segment" one.

Could use the `r` value to testing for "segment" exclusion.

```
if (r > 1.0) return 0;
```